# Convert every part of IP number to three digit in C

Tags: c, ip, digits

My question is how to convert every part of IP number to three digits? For example `127.0.0.1` becomes `127.000.000.001`

It is easy to do in languages like Python but I am new in C and do not know how to handle it.

Comment: Use sscanf to extract to integers and then snprintf it back to a string formatting it as %3i.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char ip1[] = "127.0.0.1";

int a1, a2, a3, a4;
sscanf(ip1, "%i.%i.%i.%i", &a1, &a2, &a3, &a4);

char ip2[16];
snprintf(ip2, sizeof(ip2), "%03i.%03i.%03i.%03i", a1, a2, a3, a4);
```

Forgot the zeros in the snprintf!

Answer (score 0):

Printing an integer with "leading zeros" is done as follows:

```
int i = 9;
printf("%03i", i); // prints 009
```

So, if say your IP is stored as 4 bytes, you could try:

```
char ip[4] = {...};
printf("%03i.%03i.%03i.%03i", (int)ip[0], (int)ip[1], (int)ip[2], (int)ip[3]);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can tokenize the string using 1. strtok and 2. using strchr or strstr and than using those tokens you can check the length and do required processing.

for example (using strtok) with some changes strchr or strstr can be used

```
char s[]="127.0.0.1";
char *tokens = strtok(s,".");
while(tokens != NULL)
{

  if(strlen(tokens)!=3){
     //insert zeros till the length is not 3
  }
  tokens=strtok(NULL,".");
}
```

[this link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/) can be useful for you...

Comment: This is really not very helpful ... There's no space to "insert" anything in the array, and it's not certain the OP has a string as input to begin with.

Comment: In which other format you can store 127.0.0.1... the only option left is an array (IMHO) and if OP has the IP in an array than their wouldn't have been any problem in adding leading zeros... you may be right but a downvote is just too harsh..